# Calling a dll function C++ rad studio xe3

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, c++builder-xe3

I try to call a function from a dll, but it doesn't seem to work fine. Here is the code:

```
HMODULE  dllhandle;
#include "Unit1.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream.h>  
#include <conio.h>
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

    dllhandle = LoadLibrary((wchar_t*)"PBusDrv.dll");

if(dllhandle)
{
typedef int (*PBUSCONNECTEX)(String aux1, String aux2, String ip);
PBUSCONNECTEX PBusConnectEx;

PBusConnectEx =  (PBUSCONNECTEX)GetProcAddress(dllhandle,  "PBusConnectEx");

PBusConnectEx(" "," ","192.168.30.252");
   }
}
```

dllhandle keeps returning with a null value.

Comment: LoadLibrary(L"PBusDrv.dll");

Comment: You lied to the compiler and you reaped the just consequences of that lie.

Comment: @Chris: That's also a lie, albeit one the compiler can catch. It's either `LoadLibraryA("PBusDrv.dll");` or `LoadLibraryW(L"PBusDrv.dll");` (well, or `LoadLibrary(_T("PBusDrv.dll"));` - but that's not really useful in 2015 anymore).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is *probably* here:

```
(wchar_t*)"PBusDrv.dll"
```

You are casting an ANSI string (1 byte per char) as a wide-string (2 bytes per char). This is never going to work.

You have 3 options:

1- Use the ANSI version of the LoadLibrary function

```
dllhandle = LoadLibraryA("PBusDrv.dll");
```

2- Use the [appropriate string type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx) according to the project configuration:

```
dllhandle = LoadLibrary(_T("PBusDrv.dll"));
```

3- Use the wide-string version of LoadLibrary, while passing a wide-string as input

```
dllhandle = LoadLibraryW(L"PBusDrv.dll");
```

Note: Don't mix non-specific function macros with one particular type of string. For example, don't do this:

```
dllhandle = LoadLibrary(L"PBusDrv.dll");
```

Comment: I can also tell you that `PBusConnectEx()` DOES NOT take `String` objects (aka `System::UnicodeString` in XE3) as parameters, it takes `char*` parameters instead, and it uses the `__stdcall` calling convention.  So you need to fix the `PBUSCONNECTEX` declaration as well: `typedef int (__stdcall *PBUSCONNECTEX)(char *aux1, char *aux2, char *ip);`

Comment: @Alejandra Do you want us to debug your entire program? That would seem unfair. Especially with the lack of information. This is the answer to the question you asked. Please accept it.

Comment: not looking you to debug the entire program, just have some doubts.... the answer was just fine.... ummm thanks @yms!!!